# Access env file variables in docker-compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have an environment file that contain a variable called `Database_User`.

In my docker-compose, I have this:

```
services:
  database:
    container_name: postgres
    hostname: db
    image: postgres:12-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${Database_User}
   ports:
      - "54321:5432"
   env_file: project/myproject/.env
```

But, I am getting an error:

> The Database_User variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.

Answer (score 30):

To get this right it is important to correctly understand the differences between the `environment` and `env_file` properties and the `.env` file:

- [`environment`](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#environment) and [`env_file`](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#env_file) let you specify environment variables to be set **in the container**:

  - with `environment` you can specify the variables explicitly in the `docker-compose.yml`
  - with `env_file` you implicitly import all variables from that file
  - mixing *both* on the same service is bad practice since it will easily lead to unexpected behavior
- the [`.env` file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/) is loaded by `docker-compose` **into the environment of `docker-compose` itself** where it can be used

  - to alter the behavior of `docker-compose` with respective [CLI environment variables](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/)
  - for [variable substitution](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#substitute-environment-variables-in-compose-files) in the `docker-compose.yml`

So your current configuration does not do what you probably think it does:

```yaml
env_file: project/myproject/.env
```

Will load that `.env` file into the environment **of the container** and not of `docker-compose`. Therefor `Database_User` **won't** be set for variable substitution:

```yaml
environment:
  - POSTGRES_USER=${Database_User}
```

The solution here: remove `env_file` from your `docker-compose.yml` and place `.env` in the same directory you are starting `docker-compose` from. Alternatively you can [specify an `.env` file by path with the `--env-file` flag](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#substitute-environment-variables-in-compose-files):

```sh
docker-compose --env-file project/myproject/.env up
```

Comment: Hi , you are saying  `docker-compose` loading variables automatically , so how I can use in `environment:` ?

Comment: Have a look into the [`docker-compose` documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/), it explains all this with small examples.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**:
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65485273/4676641) clearly explains the important difference from defining environment variables in an env file vs using variable substitution in a docker-compose file. I have edited my answer for clarity but please make sure you also understand the other answer.

#### Option 1

You likely have not set the environment variable `Database_User` for variable substitution to work and need to source wherever you have that defined before running docker-compose.

```sh
source ./database_user_defined_here.env
docker-compose up
```

You can review the docs on environment variable substitution: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#substitute-environment-variables-in-compose-files

#### Option 2

If you're using an environment file, you shouldn't have to specify the `environment` section (then just define `POSTGRES_USER=...` in that file). Then you'd run:

```sh
docker-compose --env-file ./your-env-file.env up
```

Or you can also specify the env file in docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
database:
  ...
  env_file:
    - your-env-file.env
```

However, you must specify the environment variables explicitly in this file. [These](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/) docs go over env file syntax.

Comment: be sure to don't confuse the [`env_file` configuration option](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env_file-configuration-option) and the [`--env_file` flag](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#substitute-environment-variables-in-compose-files) since they're doing very different things! see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65484277/access-env-file-variables-in-docker-compose-file/65485273#65485273)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, you explained the difference much better in your answer!

Comment: I didnt get still how I can use variables in docker-compose file . I have `.env` file

Comment: I'm not sure you understood the answers provided, my apologies. Are you talking about using arbitrary variables in your compose file like `Database_User`? If you have defined `Database_User` in your `.env` file, can run `source your.env` to set these variables before running `docker-compose up` as stated in option 1. However, make sure you do not use the `env_file` property in this case since as stated by @acran, mixing these can easily to unexpected behavior.