# Docker variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string (using env_file)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I'm trying to set `env_file` to a file with several environment variables for my postgreSQL connection string but when I run `docker-compose build`, I get this error:

```
time="2023-10-16T16:43:46-04:00" level=warning msg="The \"PGUSER\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2023-10-16T16:43:46-04:00" level=warning msg="The \"PGPASSWORD\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2023-10-16T16:43:46-04:00" level=warning msg="The \"PGDATABASE\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2023-10-16T16:43:46-04:00" level=warning msg="The \"PGPORT\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2023-10-16T16:43:46-04:00" level=warning msg="The \"PGPORT\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
1 error(s) decoding:

* error decoding 'ports': No port specified: :<empty>
```

Here is my docker-compose:

```yaml
version: "3.11"
services:
 app:
  container_name: app_container
  build: .
  volumes:
   - .:/django
  ports:
   - 8000:8000
  image: app:django
  command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
  depends_on:
   - db
 db:
  container_name: postgres_container
  env_file:
   - .env.prod
  image: postgres
  restart: always
  environment:
   POSTGRES_USER: ${PGUSER}
   POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${PGPASSWORD}
   POSTGRES_DB: ${PGDATABASE}
  ports:
   - "${PGPORT}:${PGPORT}"
 pgadmin:
  container_name: pgadmin4_container
  image: dpage/pgadmin4
  restart: always
  environment:
   PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@admin.com
   PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: Password12345
  ports:
   - "5050:80"
```

Here is my `env_file`:

```properties
PGHOST="127.0.0.1"
PGUSER="postgres"
PGPORT=5432
PGDATABASE="dev_db"
PGPASSWORD="postgres"
```

As you can see, they are in the same directory.

[image: VSCode]

Comment: Why are the names yellow?  Is that an indicator that you forgot to save them?

Comment: @JohnGordon probably just VCS (git status) highlighting

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access env file variables in docker-compose file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65484277/access-env-file-variables-in-docker-compose-file)

Comment: @Phil this link does not. I have the env file and the docker-compose in the same directory. I don't understand how they want me to import my environment variables like `PGPORT`, `PGUSER`, `PGPASSWORD`, AND `PGDATABASE`.

Comment: Big difference between `env_file` used in your `docker-compose.yml` file and a `.env` file that Compose can use for configuration. The top-voted answer makes that pretty clear

Comment: If you want to use your `.env.prod` file for configuration, run Compose with `docker compose --env-file .env.prod ...`

Comment: I figured out if I just remove the environment section and change `.env.prod` to just `.env`, everything works fine. I don't understand why I can't have `.env.prod` the name of an `env_file`.

Answer (score 0):

as docker-compose checks **.env** file while you run the command. for the best experiment, you should define your custom env file name in command only like:

`docker compose --env-file .env.prod up`

Another thing you should name the env file as .env only.

Also If you are Using `.env.prod` File as an env file then you should define this as Documented On docker Documentations.

```html
env_file:
  - ./a.env
  - ./b.env
```

You can check More docker Docs Here: [docker Services top-level element](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#env_file)

Answer (score 0):

[The solution is to use single quote instead of double quote in `.env` file.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73575077/6141587).

#### .env

```
### USE THIS
HONEYPOT_SECRET='bUTtBM$mw*3ZoDr7t#aa12F$SM%0'
### INSTEAD OF THIS
HONEYPOT_SECRET="bUTtBM$mw*3ZoDr7t#aa12F$SM%0"
```